# Nvidia Drivers failing after updating with Update Manager

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, gpu-driver

I'm currently using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. After installing all available updates for my system, and a reboot, the following error message shows up:

```
Starting load fallback graphics devices [fail]
```

I couldn't run any commands, and the system didn't respond to Ctrl + Alt + Del. But if I pressed the power button on my computer the system responded and shutdown the system successfully.

After powering up again, the only sign of life was a blinking underscore.  Lucky me, **I had a backup** that I restored. I understand that it's probably the Nvidia drivers that's "broken". So, after restoring my backup, I'm willing to make a successful system update, and preferably without needing to restore my backup.

About a year ago or so when I installed Ubuntu on my computer, the Additional Drivers Windows looked like this:

[image]

I installed the Recommended version. Now, a year later, my Additional Drivers windows look like this:
[image]

The bottom two is identical, while the top two are two different versions, 304.108 and
304.88. Here's the description of the four different drivers: http://pastebin.com/j2RD1mD4

The latest driver according to the description(s) is number 2.

What should I do? Or more like, what would you do?

Should I install all updated except the Nvidida ones, or should I try to install the latest one from the Additional Drivers, or what?

The ultimate would be to have the latest Nvidida drivers installed, together with a fully updated system.

The following Nvidia related updates is available in the Update Manager, and one/some of them is probably the reason why the graphics is malfunctioning.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the Nvidia driver v 304.108 from [here](http://www.nvidia.com/content/DriverDownload-March2009/confirmation.php?url=/XFree86/Linux-x86/304.108/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.108.run&lang=us&type=GeForce)
2. Install the driver manually [This link will help you](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-304.108-driver)
3. To install it manually

First press ctrl + alt +f1 This will open tty1

Now you are using the tty terminal console

log in with your user name and password

Now stop the lightdm(dgm or whatever) using the command

```
sudo stop lightdm
```

Then install the new driver with

```
sudo sh /path-to-the-driver
```

- if something goes wrong close the installer and reboot then try again
- still same problem the nvidia installer will make a black list in /etc/modprobe.d/
- if this is not generated you have to make such file to black list nouveau
- Run sudoedit /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf and fill it with this:
  blacklist nouveau
- If the problem is not solve you have to add the string "nomodeset" to your /etc/default/grub, in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= line
- then update the grub

  sudo update-grub

Comment: Can you please say what you mean with "In short to install it manually". And when should I press ctrl + alt + f1?

Comment: @ThePhone I mean this is a simple fast steps to install driver if you don't want to read the tutorial in the link i gave you... you have to press ctrl+alt+f1 whenever you want to start installing the driver

Comment: Okey, so I install the driver manuallt without uninstalling my current driver. Then I just press ctrl + alt + f1, or should I reboot and assume that it will get stuck and then press ctrl alt f1? Sorry, I'm a little slow with linux stuff :)

Comment: just press it now and you don't need to uninstall your driver

Comment: Nothing happens if I press the combination. Have I understood you right that after installing the .run file, I just press ctrl +alt +f1. In the tty1, you mean after rebooting? Please give more step by step so I understand more easily.

Comment: you have to log in tty1 first before installing the .run file... check the edit

Comment: I want to remind you that I restored a backup, so I'm currently logged in to Unity, When I press  ctrl + alt +f1 nothing happens. Do you mean that I should just open the terminal, like ctrl + alt + T?

Comment: When u r in unity and you press ctrl+alt+f[1 to 6] you will beswitched to a cli console called tty[1 to 6]...

Comment: I'm sorry, but nothing happens. I press CTRL, ALT and f1, f2 f3 etc. Nothing happens. And I'm in Unity.

Comment: http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=8883   To fix this problem

Comment: Can't I just open a regular terminal as root? The combination doesn't make anything at all. It's just like I didn't press it.

Comment: Try it, but i dont think so since you have to kill all GUI inorder to install the nvidia driver anyay try to do the steps in regular terminal

Comment: Okey, I try, and resturn with the result

Comment: BTW can't I install it from the Update Manager, so it get's install right? EDIT: I mean from the  Additional Drivers window

Comment: you have to specify the version as 304.108... I passed this before and i didn't find any solution other than i gave u above

Comment: Wait I meant from the Additional Drivers window! It actually finds the 304.108. I can activate/install it from there.

Comment: ah ok if you find it then go and install it from there

Comment: yeah I wrote that in the question. But that's allright. Thanks for all the help so far! Your great!